# React Native Download Youtube video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried many examples but all of them are not working. Many blog suggested many things.
for example ;

add library youtube-video-downloader ,
add ffbge ,
add ,
bla bla

My question is simple : how to download youtube video as mp3 in local system in REACT NATIVE ?
Do you have any example ?

Comment: I also have the same problem, but as I understand it without a backend, there is no way to do it